# Which file type to use for these fonts, and how compatible each is for Android 4.1.2?

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, customization, fonts

#### Just a few things...

- This question might perhaps have a poor title, but I couldn't figure out how to word it better, so bear with me.
- I originally asked where to ask this question [on SE Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277086/where-to-ask-case-specific-questions-about-android-fonts/277089#277089), which [directed me to here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/277089/297765).
- I know there are [numerous apps out there](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=fonts&c=apps&docType=1&sp=CAFiBwoFZm9udHN6BRgAwAECigECCAE%3D:S:ANO1ljIQhAQ) that can find the appropriate files for me, but I have no interest in these things, so please don't suggest any of them.

---

#### Some Details

I have a specific list of 5 fonts that I would like to install, if possible, on my Android device:

- [EB Garamond](http://www.georgduffner.at/ebgaramond/index.html)
- [Liberation (font family)](https://fedorahosted.org/liberation-fonts/)
- [Inconsolata](http://www.levien.com/type/myfonts/inconsolata.html)
- [Roboto](https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Roboto)
- [Open Sans](https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Open+Sans)

According to the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760709/what-font-file-types-does-android-support), both TTF and OTF files are supported by Android, TTF always but OTF since about version 1.6. (The [original links cited](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8760782/5071510) back this up.) So you sort of either have to have the knowledge of how compatible the font is before using it or you need to have the patience to fiddle around with it if anything crops up afterwards.

I have neither: I'm used to installing fonts on desktop OSs, not mobile ones, so I'm not sure which ones are compatible, and I usually prefer to know how software or files are going to affect my ability to do my stuff (aesthetically or functionally) before I use them.

#### The Question

All I need—nothing too complicated—is the following: for each font listed above, please tell me if only the TTF or OTF file, or both, or neither (hey, you never know), is compatible; which one—TTF or OTF—is most compatible (if applicable); and how compatible I can expect said file to be with my particular version of Android.

---

#### Specs

- *Make & Model*: Samsung Galaxy Stratosphere II
- *Operating System*: Android v4.1.2 JB